How to not run or stop Oracle 23 JDBC Driver Diagnostic.CLOCK thread?
Just updated to the Oracle 23 JDBC driver and when I shutdown Tomcat I now get the following warning:
WARNING: The web application [xx] appears to have started a thread named [oracle.jdbc.diagnostics.Diagnostic.CLOCK] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
java.base@11.0.18/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
java.base@11.0.18/java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:553)
java.base@11.0.18/java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:506)

I have tried everything I can think of to prevent this but I have not been able to.
Anyone know how to stop this?

Diagnostic.CLOCK thread is used by the JDBC diagnostics/logging framework internally. I believe this is a WARNING raised by your Tomcat server when you stop/undeploy your application. It should be safe to ignore this warning, however this issue/warning has been fixed in the upcoming JDBC driver release i.e. 23.4.
